# /bin/sh: eval: line 126: –: not found when trying to build a packer image with Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, packer

I'm trying to set up a Gitlab pipeline for my packer builds and I'm getting this error when trying to build the packer image

`/bin/sh: eval: line 126: –: not found`

Here's my **.gitlab-ci.yml** file as well:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

image: alpine

get_packer:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - packer
  script:
    - echo "Fetching packer"
    - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/1.5.5/packer_1.5.5_linux_amd64.zip
    - unzip packer_1.5.5_linux_amd64.zip
    - chmod +x packer

deploy_packer:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    – echo "Deploying Packer Build"
    – cd aws
    – ./packer build -only="*rhel*" .
```

The build stage passes, I just get that error during the deploy stage.

Here's the last few lines from my pipeline leading up to the error. I've seen other examples just like this, what could be causing it?

```
Downloading artifacts for get_packer (3446587702)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=3446587702 responseStatus=200 OK token=-s1LvCfZ
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:49176f190c7e9cdb51ac85ab6c6d5e4512352218190cd69b08e6fd803ffbf3da for alpine with digest alpine@sha256:8914eb54f968791faf6a8638949e480fef81e697984fba772b3976835194c6d4 ...
/bin/sh: eval: line 126: –: not found
$ – echo "Deploying Packer Build" – cd aws – ./packer build -only="*rhel*" .
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

Comment: Use `-` character, not `–`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I'm a little confused, what line(s) are using the incorrect `-` character?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I see what it was, that did the trick!